# Lilypond: Align markup on a specific arg

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I created a new dynamic marking using the method described [in the documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-attached-to-notes#new-dynamic-marks).

What I have is this:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"

subitoMF = \markup { 
  \italic subito 
  \dynamic mf 
}

{ 
f'_\subitoMF
}
```

Is there a way to horizontally align this markup solely around the dynamic "mf" argument so that that part is easily centered on the notehead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this would be an option. Note that doing custom dynamics should not use ^-_ with markups, but `#(make-dynamic-script ...)`. See the example for details, and also for why this matters.

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"

#(define-markup-command (add-left layout props m1 m2) (markup? markup?)
   (let* ((stc1 (interpret-markup layout props m1))
          (stc2 (interpret-markup layout props m2)))
     (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stc2 X LEFT stc1 0.6)))


submf =
\tweak self-alignment-X ##f
#(make-dynamic-script
  (markup
   #:add-left
   #:normal-text #:italic "subito"
   #:dynamic #:center-align "mf"))


subitoMF = \markup { 
  \add-left
  \italic subito 
  \center-align
  \dynamic mf 
}

{ 
R1 f'_\subitoMF\> f' f' f' f'1\p R1 f'4\submf\> f' f' f' f'1\p
}
```

Comment: > Note that doing custom dynamics [etc.]  
I tried make-dynamic-script first but being a noob in Scheme I didn't know how to best work with halignment.  

I read up on creating markup commands to understand what you did. The command you created is very useful. I added the following when the marking appeared in the 1st beat of a bar in the middle of a system in order to avoid an unseemly space at the beginning of the bar:  

\once \override DynamicText.X-extent = #'(-2 . 2)  
      \once \override DynamicText.whiteout-style = #'box  
      \once \override DynamicText.whiteout = ##t

Comment: @PedroTecla Sure. Note that instead of setting `DynamicText.whiteout` to `#t` you can also set it to a number, which would then be used as padding for the whiteout. E.g.  `\once \override DynamicText.whiteout = #1.3` or something.